Working through a difficult integral, I got stuck evaluating the subsequent integral $\int_\theta^{\theta+\pi}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{a - b\sin x}}dx$
I started with the following integral:
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{\gamma - \alpha\Big(a\cos\theta + b\sin\theta\Big)}}; \text{ assume }\gamma > \alpha\Big(a\cos\theta + b\sin\theta\Big) \text{ for all } \theta$$
factoring out $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ from $(a\cos\theta + b\sin\theta)$ and writing $k = \alpha \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ turns this problem into:
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin\theta d\theta}{\sqrt{\gamma - k\sin(\beta+\theta)[1]}} = \int_\beta^{\beta+\pi}\frac{\sin(z-\beta)dz}{\sqrt{\gamma - k\sin z}}$$
Putting this into a more general form (which we will use for the remainder of the problem):
$$\tag{1}\int_\theta^{\theta+\pi} \frac{\sin(x-\theta)}{\sqrt{a - b\sin x}}dx$$
I can then rewrite $\sin(x-\theta) = \sin x\cos \theta - \cos x\sin \theta$ and our integral becomes:
$$\tag{2}\cos \theta\int_\theta^{\theta+\pi} \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{a - b\sin x}}dx - \sin \theta\int_\theta^{\theta+\pi} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{a - b\sin x}}dx$$
and I can evaluate the second integral without much difficulty by simply subbing in $u^2 = a-b\sin x, -\frac{2u}{b}du = \cos x dx$
And I'm left with:
$$\tag{3}= \cos \theta \underbrace{\int_\theta^{\theta+\pi}\frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{a - b\sin x}}dx} + \frac{2\sin(\theta)}{b}\Big(\sqrt{a-b\sin(\theta+\pi)}-\sqrt{a-b\sin \theta}\Big)$$
where I'm stuck trying to integrate the bracketed integral.

[1]We made substitutions $\sin\beta = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}, \cos\beta = \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, and this can be done because $\Bigg(\frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\Bigg)^2 + \Bigg(\frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}\Bigg)^2 = \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2}$ satisfies the argument $\sin\beta^2 + \cos\beta^2 = 1$

EDIT:
by u-substitution $u = a-b\sin x$:
$$-\frac{1}{b}\int_{a-b\sin\theta}^{a-b\sin(\theta+\pi)}\frac{a-u}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{(a+b-u)(u+b-a)}}$$
What should I do next?

Maple evaluates this in terms of elliptic integrals $E$ and $F$.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral  I think substitution $u=a-b\sin x$ converts it to an integral involving square-root of a cubic polynomial.

@GEdgar doing the u-sub as you suggested gives the following integral: $$-\frac{1}{b^2}\int_{a-b\sin\theta}^{a-b\sin(\theta+\pi)}\frac{a-u}{\sqrt{u}\sqrt{1-\frac{a-u}{b}^2}} du$$. So this square root in the denominator is factorable from there?

@user170231 I cannot visually extrapolate the substitutions you have performed, could you please provide more details? Also the first integral would be this and the second integral would be this, right?

@ResearcherR You might be interested in these notes on elliptic integral reduction: https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~glabahn/Papers/ellipticPrePrint.pdf

For $0<\theta<\dfrac\pi2$ and $a>b$, consider the integral
$$\begin{align*}
I(\theta) &= \int_0^\theta \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{a-b\sin x}} \, dx \\
&= 4 \int_0^\tfrac\theta2 \frac{\sin x\cos x}{\sqrt{a-2b\sin x\cos x}} \, dx & x\to2x \\
&= \frac4{\sqrt a} \int_0^{\tan\tfrac\theta2} \frac x{\left(1+x^2\right)^{3/2} \sqrt{1-\frac{2b}a x + x^2}} \, dx & x\to\arctan x \\
&= 2 \int_{\tan\left(\tfrac\pi4-\tfrac\theta2\right)}^1 \frac{1-x^2}{\left(1+x^2\right)^{3/2}\sqrt{\alpha+\beta x^2}} \, dx & x\to\frac{1-x}{1+x} \\
&= 2 \int_{\sqrt{\tfrac{1-\sin\theta}2}}^\tfrac1{\sqrt2} \frac{1-2x^2}{\sqrt{1-x^2} \sqrt{\alpha+(\beta-\alpha)x^2}} \, dx & x\to\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \\
&= \frac2{\sqrt\alpha} \int_{\sqrt{\tfrac{1-\sin\theta}2}}^\tfrac1{\sqrt2} \underbrace{\left[\frac{2\sqrt{1-x^2}}{\sqrt{1+\gamma x^2}}-\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2} \sqrt{1+\gamma x^2}}\right]}_{f(x)} \, dx
\end{align*}$$
where $(\alpha,\beta)=(a-b,a+b)$ and $\gamma=\dfrac{\beta-\alpha}\alpha=\dfrac{2b}{a-b}$. Note that the chain of substitutions used here can be shortened to a single step,
$$x \to -2 \arctan \frac{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x+\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$
The remaining two expressions are incomplete elliptic integrals. The second more immediately evaluates to an EI of the first kind.
The first term needs some additional massaging with a step of substituting $x\to\dfrac x{\sqrt{-\gamma}}$, which transforms the integrand to
$$\frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}\gamma}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
and from here one can extract an EI of the second kind, albeit of at least one complex argument.
So, we should end up with something quite messy like
$$\begin{align*}
I(\theta) &= \frac4{\sqrt{-\alpha\gamma}} \int_{\sqrt{-\gamma\tfrac{1-\sin\theta}2}}^\sqrt{-\tfrac\gamma2} \frac{\sqrt{1+\frac{x^2}\gamma}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \, dx- \frac2{\sqrt\alpha} \int_{\sqrt{\tfrac{1-\sin\theta}2}}^\tfrac1{\sqrt2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\sqrt{1+\gamma x^2}} \\[1ex]
&= \frac4{\sqrt{-\alpha\gamma}} \left[E\left(\arcsin \sqrt{-\frac\gamma2} ; -\frac1\gamma\right) - E\left(\arcsin \sqrt{-\gamma\frac{1-\sin\theta}2} ; -\frac1\gamma\right)\right] \\
&\qquad - \frac2{\sqrt\alpha} \left[F\left(\frac\pi4 ; -\gamma\right) - F\left(\arcsin\sqrt{\frac{1-\sin\theta}2} ; -\gamma\right)\right] \\[1ex]
&= \frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{-b}} \left[E\left(\arcsin \sqrt{\frac b{b-a}} ;\frac{b-a}{2b}\right) - E\left(\arcsin \sqrt{\frac b{b-a}(1-\sin\theta)} ;\frac{b-a}{2b}\right) \right] \\
&\qquad - \frac2{\sqrt{a-b}} \left[F\left(\frac\pi4 ; \frac{2b}{b-a}\right) - F\left(\frac\pi4-\frac\theta2 ; \frac{2b}{b-a}\right)\right]
\end{align*}$$
Finally, as an extra step that I'll forego, we can remove a factor of $i$ from the surviving $\arcsin$ arguments to rewrite e.g.
$$\arcsin \sqrt{\frac b{b-a}} = \arcsin \left(i \sqrt{\frac b{a-b}}\right) = i \operatorname{arsinh}\sqrt{\frac b{a-b}}$$
Here is a Wolfram cloud notebook containing a handful of random trials comparing the numerical values of this special case of OP's integral with the "closed form" found above for various real $\theta$ and $a>b$. Both forms of $I(\theta)$ agree to at least six significant digits. The output of results and results2 resp. correspond to $I(\theta)$ and $J(\theta)$ (see below).
When $\theta=\dfrac\pi2$, we have
$$I\left(\frac\pi2\right) = \frac{2\sqrt2}{\sqrt{-b}} E\left(\arcsin \sqrt{\frac b{b-a}} ;\frac{b-a}{2b}\right) - \frac2{\sqrt{a-b}} F\left(\frac\pi4 ; \frac{2b}{b-a}\right)$$

If $\dfrac\pi2<\theta<\pi$, we first split up $I(\theta) = I\left(\dfrac\pi2\right) + J(\theta)$ and evaluate $J$ as follows. Except for a preliminary phase shift and omitting the third substitution used above, the steps are the same.
$$\begin{align*}
J(\theta) &= \int_\tfrac\pi2^\theta \frac{\sin x}{\sqrt{a - b\sin x}} \, dx \\
&= \int_0^{\theta-\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{a - b\cos x}} \, dx & x\to x+\frac\pi2 \\
&= \frac2{\sqrt\alpha} \int_0^{\sqrt{\tfrac{1-\sin\theta}2}} f(x) \, dx & x\to2\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\equiv2\arcsin x
\end{align*}$$

My internet is finally back up! Upon digging back up $\theta$ from its substitutions and thoroughly working through it, I do believe you were correct in asserting that $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$, so everything else thereafter (which I haven't yet parsed through), assuming it hinges on that range for $\theta$, should be correct. That was one thing I wasn't quite certain on when I when I saw it, so I needed to take some extra time to explore where it was coming from. I will take some time to read through the rest, and hopefully what David H has provided can help reduce these elliptic integrals.

This interval is necessary to apply the tangent half-angle substitution directly. It's the same reason for the phase shift in the first step in evaluating $J$. Also, in case it helps to break down each step, you might want to replace each instance of substituting $x\to F(x)$ with an explicit variable change, $x=F(\text{new variable})$. Best of luck!
